# Node gm - use crop and resize cause error

Tags: node.js, resize, crop, graphicsmagick

The following code throw an error.

> Error: Command failed: gm convert: geometry does not contain image
>   (unable to crop image).

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('/origin.jpg')
.resize(600)
.write('/beforeCrop', function (err) {
    // beforeCrop is 600 * 450
    gm('/beforeCrop')
    .crop(70, 70, 100, 100)
    .resize(50, 50)
    .write('/result', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Is seem that gm can not resolve the size of **beforeCrop**.

Answer (score 4):

Why not piping to a stream and reading from it on the fly?

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('/origin.jpg')
.resize(600)
.stream(function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    // beforeCrop is 600 * 450
    gm(stdout) // gm can read buffers ;)
    .crop(70, 70, 100, 100)
    .resize(50, 50)
    .write('/result', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

I'd also consider piping to another stream after cropping like so:

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('/origin.jpg')
.resize(600)
.stream(function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    // beforeCrop is 600 * 450
    gm(stdout) // gm can read buffers ;)
    .crop(70, 70, 100, 100).stream(function (err,stdout,stderr) {
        gm(stdout).resize(50, 50)
        .write('/result', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    });
});
```

I had some problems when doing both on the same chain.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be reading from and writing to your system's root directory. Unless you're running as root/administrator, you won't have the right permissions to do that, and if you are, you're probably (certainly if this is part of a Web server) opening up a gigantic security hole.

Comment: I used / just for simplicity.

Comment: How 'bout responding to error conditions everywhere they could arise, like in your first `.write`, and doing so with a `console.log()` that explains which step of the process the error is occuring at (in async code, a mere stack trace won't tell you that)?

Comment: It seems to work if I keep the extension of the original image. See my closed [issue on github](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/78#issuecomment-8640636).