# How can I copy a section of an image using the gm node package?

Tags: php, node.js, meteor

I've installed [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) node package and I need to be able to copy a section of an image.  I'm not sure if its possible to do it using this package.

In PHP it looks like the function I would be looking for is [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)

This is about as close as I've got so far:

```
var im = gm.subClass({imageMagick: true});
im(source)
.crop(coords.w, coords.h)
.write(projectRootServer + 'forrestregion.png', function(err){
   if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
   console.log(this.outname + ' created :: ' + arguments[3])
})
```

I thought the .region function might do the job but it doesn't look like it.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: I don't mean to sound naive, but doesn't `.crop` expect 4 arguments ? or does it assume you're starting at `0/0` if you only provide 2 arguments? [Check the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13187866/1206267), does that help?

Comment: That does look like it solves it!  How did I miss that lol!  Passed in x & y and it seems to work as expected.